# how to add a custom summaryitem to devexpress gridcontrol

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, devexpress

I have a summary field in footer of a gridcontrol. In the gridcontrol, I have CheckButtons on the first column for users to select the records to process on. I need to fix summary field only to sum selected rows. Now it sums every row. How can I get it sum only the selected rows?

[image]

Comment: Maybe: [How to calculate summary for Selected Rows](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q337226) or http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q359847

Comment: Your screen shot doesn't show check buttons. And I'm unsure of whether that summary field is a part of the grid view control or something you've created on the form. And it probably depends a lot on what kind of data objects you have bound to the grid control as data source.

Comment: @RenniePet, that summary field is part of the gridview, and it sums all whether selected or not

Comment: OK, I've used XtraGrid a fair amount, but never the summary fields. Did Soner Gönül's link solve the problem for you? If not, and if you'd like me to take a crack at it, please post the definition of the class that is the data source object, i.e., that represents each row, and also the collection object (List<> or whatever).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change [`GridColumn.SummaryItem.SummaryType`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridGridSummaryItem_SummaryTypetopic) property to [`SummaryItemType.Custom`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressDataSummaryItemTypeEnumtopic) and use [`GridView.CustomSummaryCalculate`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_CustomSummaryCalculatetopic) event to set the value of summary. But you cannot obtain information about selected rows in `GridView.CustomSummaryCalculate` event. That's why you need to calculate your sum in `GridView.SelectionChanged` event and use this sum in `GridView.CustomSummaryCalculate` event.
Here is example:

```
private int _selectedSum;
private string _fieldName = "TOPLAM";

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var column = gridView1.Columns[_fieldName];
    column.SummaryItem.SummaryType = SummaryItemType.Custom;
}

private void gridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var column = gridView1.Columns[_fieldName];

    switch (e.Action)
    {
        case CollectionChangeAction.Add:
            _selectedSum += (int)gridView1.GetRowCellValue(e.ControllerRow, column);
            break;
        case CollectionChangeAction.Remove:
            _selectedSum -= (int)gridView1.GetRowCellValue(e.ControllerRow, column);
            break;
        case CollectionChangeAction.Refresh:

            _selectedSum = 0;

            foreach (var rowHandle in gridView1.GetSelectedRows())
                _selectedSum += (int)gridView1.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, column);

            break;
    }

    gridView1.UpdateTotalSummary();
}

private void gridView1_CustomSummaryCalculate(object sender, CustomSummaryEventArgs e)
{
    var item = e.Item as GridColumnSummaryItem;

    if (item == null || item.FieldName != _fieldName)
        return;

    if (e.SummaryProcess == CustomSummaryProcess.Finalize)
        e.TotalValue = _selectedSum;
}
```